# Moment JS : Convert TimeZone Date to Local Time Zone

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, localtime

I am using [Date Picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker)

I get value from Database as **2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z** .

While assigning this value to DatePicker, I want this Format

**Wed May 6 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

Note: **GMT+530 (Indian Standard Time)** may be different based on System Time.

How can I do that ?

I have used moment library.

but it gives me this output : **2020-05-06 05:30:00**

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

```js
 let date = '2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z'
 
 let dateValue = moment(date).local().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
 
 console.log("Date : " , dateValue)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using toDate() function of moment Library as it fetches time zone from your local system

```
let dateValue = moment(date).local().toDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom format

Wed May 6 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530

```
'ddd MMM D YYYY HH:MM:SS [GMT]ZZ'
```

ddd = 3 character weekday

MMM = 3 character month

D = 1 or 2 digit day of month

YYYY = 4 digit year

HH:MM:SS needs no explanation

[GMT] escaped string inside the format string

ZZ = local timezone as offset from Zulu time

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by setting the UTC flag on the moment object and then converting to a localized moment object and then formatting as required.

For your input

```js
var test = moment.utc("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z");
var localDate = moment(test).local();
console.log(localDate.format("ddd MMM D YYYY HH:MM:SS [GMT]Z"));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```